# How to access local variables from outside a function in order to test them

Tags: python, python-unittest

While writing tests for my application I want to go sure that the local variables inside my function are set correctly.

Therefore I was wondering if there is a way to catch these variables while running a test, because the tested function has no return value and I don't want to change that.

```py
 model_checkpoint = torch.load(self.model_path, map_location='cpu')
 model = model_checkpoint['model']
 label_names = model_checkpoint['labels']
```

In my example shown above, I'm interested in the value of `model`and `label_names`to check whether the loading process was successful.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: why would you test `torch`'s code? I'd assume it works, since it's a pretty popular package

Comment: Local variables are an implementation detail. It doesn't matter what their values are as long as the function has the correct return value and/or side effects: *those* are what you want to test.

Comment: Your reasoning aside, there is no simple way in test frameworks like `unittest` or `pytest` to watch variables that are local to a function. As long as you don't want to change your code in order to make that test possible (which you shouldn't) it will be very hard to achieve, I think.

Comment: More to the point, `torch` includes its own tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by splitting it into two tests. One tests the load function and the other tests the function using the result by mocking it to a known state:

```py
from unittest import TestCase, mock
import torch

class LoadTests(TestCase):
    def test_load_model(self):
        expected = construct_test_model_here
        self.assertDictEqual(expected, torch.load("path/to/test/model/", map_location='cpu'))

    @mock.patch("torch.load")
    def test_my_function(self, mock):
        mock.return_value = construct_test_model_here
        result = self.my_function()
        # check return value or side effects (better mock those too)
```

Generally you can't watch the local variables directly, but if their values are constructed elsewhere you can mock the return value of that external construction.